# Can I remove a company's logo from a software licensed under Mozilla Public License Version 1.1?

Tags: licensing, mpl

I have tried looking for an answer to this question, but I couldn't find anything related.

To put it in a nutshell, I want to fork the existing Komodo Edit project, which is licensed under MPL Version 1.1, and create a new derived project/software. I would like to remove certain features from the current project, including ActiveState's logo, but I do not understand the technical jargon on the license. Also, I plan to keep the derived project completely free and open-source.

I'd be really grateful, if someone could explain it to me.

Here is the link to the license : https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/trunk/LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 4):

The license allows you to create a fork, if you follow the rules that can be summarized as

- Your fork must use the same license
- You must state clearly and prominently that your fork is derived from KomodoEdit

The project did not contain any explicit text regarding the use of ActiveState's logo (at least not in the obvious places where I looked), but according to Komodo Edit's website, the names Komodo and ActiveState are trademarks, so it is likely that the logo is a trademark as well.

As the logo (likely) and name are trademarked, you can not use them in your fork without a separate explicit permission from ActiveState. (mentioning that your fork is derived from KomodoEdit doesn't count as 'use' in this sense, but you should acknowledge that those names are trademarks)